# Having internal website search as Google search result

Tags: seo, google, google-search, search

Sorry if this has been asked before.

Let's assume there is a website as www.example.com and there is a private search engine with URLs simmilar to www.example.com/search/search+pattern

How do I have Google display the above URLs "forwarded" for seach text entered in Google search? I mean that if one searches for example "aston martin DB7" one of the results would be www.example.com/search/aston%20martin%20DB7.

I tend to see that kind of behavior every now and then and keep wondering...

Answer (score 1):

As long as Google can get to a URL they will crawl and index it. So if you link to your search results in a sitemap, page content, or XML sitemap they will be able to find it.

Comment: Is this what happens or is there a way to have google index search result which haven't even been searched on example.com before?

Comment: So do they generate links to search results pages for a lot of common searches?